# Use try/except to handle multiple plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, try-catch

I'm generating an image composed of several individual plots. Since any one of them can fail to be generated (for various reasons), I'm using `try / except` to handle each one separately.

This is an example of what I'm doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))  # create the top-level container
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(10, 5)       # create a GridSpec object

# Define lots of arguments to feed each plot.

try:
    plot1(*args1)
except:
    print 'Failed to generate plot1'

try:
    plot2(*args2)
except:
    print 'Failed to generate plot2'

try:
    plot3(*args3)
except:
    print 'Failed to generate plot3'

try:
    plot4(*args4)
except:
    print 'Failed to generate plot4'

...

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('out_image.png', dpi=300)
```

Each `plotX()` function is unique (totalling almost 30) and generates a single plot in the final image which contains all of them.

The question is: is this a correct use of `try/except`? It seems a bit ugly and repetitive to me, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap `plotX(*args)` into another function, `plot(N, *args)`. Then you can do a loop like this:

```
for n, args in enumerate(list_of_arglists, 1):
    plot(n, *args)
```

So `plot` would look like this:

```
def plot(n, *args):
    plotter_map = {
        1: plot1,
        2: plot2,
        3: plot3,
        # ...,
        N: plotN
    }

    fxn = plotter_map.get(N, None)
    if fxn is None:
        raise ValueError("there is no `plot{}`".format(N))

    try:
        fxn(*args)
    except:
        print("failed to run `plot{}`".format(N))
```

easy peasy.

Comment: Doing this basically means putting all the plotting functions in a single file wrapped with multiple `try/except` statements. How is this any different from what I already have?

Comment: Not a single file, a single function. Without seeing any of the existing plotting functions, how am I supposed to know how similar or different they are? This is the best answer I can give you with the information you provided. You said you didn't want all of those try/except blocks, so I abstracted them away. More information = better answers.

Comment: Sorry Paul, I've added a cmmt on how each function is _unique_. +1 for the answer.

Comment: @Gabriel how does that look?

Comment: Wonderful @Paul, this is much better than my original structure. Thank you! (I've fixed an extra `:` symbol in your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the iterations outside of the method. This way the method doesn't have to change depending on the number of plots you want to generate.

```
def plot_args(args, functionToCall, count):
    try: 
        funtionToCall(args)
    except:
        print('Failed to generate plot  ' + str(count) + '.')

args_list = [(args1, plot1), (args2, plot2) ..., (argsn, plotn)] # Make a list of all args to be processed.
count = 1
for i in args_list:
    plot_args(i[0], i[1], count)
    count +=1
```

Comment: Each `plotX()` is a _different_ function. This assumes there is only one function for which only the arguments change.

Comment: Is there a way where you could pass the argument and its associated function to this function and call said unique functions within the try block?